# tmux does not render borders properly

Tags: tmux, gentoo

I am using tmux on a Gentoo Linux hardened system running kernel 3.18.9. When I run programs that display borders on the terminal such as `nmon` directly under my terminal or under `screen`, they display fine.

[image: nmon under screen]

However, when I run such programs under `tmux`, the borders appear like Unicode error characters and some parts of the program output are mangled.

[image: nmon under tmux]

I've already tried setting different values for `$TERM` environment variable and it doesn't work. I can't figure out what does `tmux` have that somehow makes its terminal different from `screen`. What's happening here?

Comment: `tmux` inserts itself as a layer between whatever was running before and the programs it runs - probably a shell. It does this with a pty. It also interprets its own escapes and channels all i/o that is passed out above it - so it puts its fingers in all of your business. You'd do better with a more simple layer - `tmux` is a monster. Anyway, changing `$TERM` is not all you need - you'll also need to ensure that `tmux` supports all of the escapes and characters specified in its alternate character sets.  The fact is, it just might not.

Comment: It _is_ a `TERM` problem, it works fine here with `xterm` 318, `tmux` 1.9a, and `TERM=xterm-screen-256color`.  However, `xterm-screen-256color` is a special `termcap` / `terminfo` entry that I had to install manually.  __Edit:__ [here](https://gist.github.com/a35d7d4f67c6ca075394).

Answer (score 2):

Just to share my experience.
I did struggle today with tmux and linux mint 17
Border in tmux were not ok since last updates. (? i.s.o - or |)
I tried lots of things without success.

What did solve my problem at the end:
  - go to setting -> Languages
  - set Language to English,United kingdom UTF-8 (or other UTF-8)
  - set Region to French-Belgium UTF-8
  - then apply system-wide
  - and REBOOT linux !

After that problem with tmux was gone.